# XPATH PHP search text and replace by class

Tags: php

I use the tinymce editor to create default "templates of text/invoices/etc.." with inside some special string like `{NAME}`, `{SURNAME}`.

From another page in my webapp, I retrieve these templates and using PHP, I replace `{NAME}` with – for example – `JOE`, etc.

This is ok, it is simple for me. Then I generate a final PDF using the TCPDF class.

But now I need to manage plugin "checklist" of tinymce and "simulate" creating the checklist in tinymce editor inside the TCPDF. I think I must use PHP XPATH but I never used it and I don't understand how to find the "complex" portion of text.

For example, the html code tinymce editor use to create 2 checkbox is:

[image]

```html
<ul class="tox-checklist">
 <li> checkbox 1</li>
 <li class="tox-checklist--checked"> checkbox 2</li>
</ul>
```

Now my goal is to convert the "checkbox" with simple square and X chars: `[  ] - [ X ]`

I know the plugin use class `.tox-checklist` to identify a UL list. And class `.tox-checklist--checked` to identify a checkbox selected.

Inside my "template" can I have multiple lists, not only one.

My final code, using I think XPATH PHP is to have this final code for TCPDF:

```html
 <p>[ ] checkbox 1</p>
 <p>[X] checkbox 2</p>
```

How can I do this complex substitution?

After some trying, I get this code working. But I'd like to know if it has some chance of simplifying:

```
 $contenuto = '<ul class="tox-checklist"><li> checkbox 1</li><li class="tox-checklist--checked"> checkbox 2</li></ul>';

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contenuto);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$selector = $xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class,"tox-checklist")]/li[not(contains(@class,"tox-checklist--checked"))]');
foreach ($selector as $node) {

    $testo_checkbox = "[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]" . $node->nodeValue;
    
    $parent = new DomDocument;
    $parent_node = $parent->createElement('p', $testo_checkbox);
    $parent->appendChild($parent_node);
    
    $newnode = $dom->importNode($parent->documentElement, true);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $node);
    
}
$contenuto = $dom->saveHTML();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contenuto);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$selector = $xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class,"tox-checklist")]/li[contains(@class,"tox-checklist--checked")]');
foreach ($selector as $node) {

    $testo_checkbox = "[ X ]" . $node->nodeValue;
    
    $parent = new DomDocument;
    $parent_node = $parent->createElement('p', $testo_checkbox);
    $parent->appendChild($parent_node);
    
    $newnode = $dom->importNode($parent->documentElement, true);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $node);
    
}
$contenuto = $dom->saveHTML();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contenuto);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$selector = $xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class,"tox-checklist")]');
foreach ($selector as $node) {
    $newParent = $node->parentNode;
    foreach ( $node->childNodes as $child ){
        $newParent->insertBefore($child->cloneNode(true), $node);
    }
    $newParent->removeChild($node);
}
$contenuto = $dom->saveHTML();
```